# System of Distributional Differential Equations

Tags: distribution-theory

[image]

Here are the problem and my attempt to the solution. Is it correct?

Comment: What does your question have to do with distribution theory?

Comment: It's in the field of distribution

Comment: The last step shouldn't be an equality, right? You take the inverse Fourier transform, don't you?

Comment: Yes, i tried to take inverse Fourier and got it, is that incorrect ?

Comment: It's not incorrect to take the inverse Fourier transform. It's incorrect, though, to write an equality in the way you do. You principally write: $\hat{f}(\xi) = f(x).$

Comment: @md2perpe Please write the correct one for me,

Comment: If you just write $\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix}$ to the left of the last equals sign, then you're good in that aspect.

Comment: However, I think that your result is not correct. The first derivative of $e^{-|x|}$ doesn't result in a $\delta$-distribution. You need the second derivative for that.

Comment: @md2perpe I am getting more confused now. Please write the correct solution for me

Comment: I don't have the correct solution yet. I'm calculating. In what way do you get confused?

Comment: Confused about generating values using the second derivative. Please post the solution when you are done with calculation.

Comment: What is the first derivative of $e^{-|x|}$? What is the second derivative?

Comment: First derivative is -exp(-|x|) if x > 0, and exp(-|x|) if x < 0, Second derivative is exp-(|x|)

Comment: I meant the distributional derivative. You have missed something.

Comment: $f'=2\delta + e^{-|x|}$ and $f" = 2\delta ' + f$

Comment: What will be the correct answer ?

Comment: That's incorrect.

Comment: What is the correct answer of this problem ?

Comment: @md2perpe, What is the correct answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix},
\quad
y = \begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{pmatrix},
\quad
b = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} \delta(x).
$$

The equation can then be written 
$y' = Ay + b.$
This can be rewritten as
$y' - Ay = b.$
After multiplication from the left with $e^{-Ax}$ we get
$e^{-Ax}y' - e^{-Ax}Ay = e^{-Ax}b.$

The left hand side can now be written as $(e^{-A}y)'$ giving
$(e^{-Ax}y)' = e^{-Ax}b,$
i.e. $e^{-Ax}y = \int e^{-Ax}b + c,$
where $c$ is a constant vector and $\int$ denotes taking antiderivative.
Thus the solution is given by
$$y = e^{Ax} \int e^{-Ax}b + e^{Ax} c.$$

Now $A^2 = I$ (check it!) so 
$$
e^{Ax} 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (Ax)^n
= \sum_{n\text{ even}} \frac{1}{n!} x^n I + \sum_{n\text{ odd}} \frac{1}{n!} x^n A
= (\cosh x) I + (\sinh x) A
$$
and
$$
e^{-Ax} = (\cosh x) I - (\sinh x) A
.
$$

This makes
$$\begin{align}
e^{-Ax} b
&= \left( (\cosh x) I - (\sinh x) A \right) b \\
&= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh x - 2 \sinh x & \sinh x \\
-3 \sinh x & \cosh x + 2 \sinh x
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
2
\end{pmatrix} \delta(x) \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \sinh x \\
2 \cosh x + 4 \sinh x
\end{pmatrix}
\delta(x) \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
2
\end{pmatrix}
\delta(x),
\end{align}$$
where the last identity holds since $f(x) \, \delta(x) = f(0) \, \delta(x).$

Now,
$$
\int e^{-Ax} b = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} H(x),
$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside function.

This gives
$$
e^{Ax} \int e^{-Ax} b
= \left( (\cosh x) I + (\sinh x) A \right)
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} H(x)
= \begin{pmatrix}-2 \sinh x \\ 2 \cosh x - 4 \sinh x\end{pmatrix} H(x).
$$

Thus the general solution is
$$
y(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \sinh x\\ 
2 \cosh x - 4 \sinh x
\end{pmatrix} H(x)
+ \begin{pmatrix}
c_1 \cosh x + 2 c_1 \sinh x - c_2 \sinh x \\
c_2 \cosh x + 3 c_1 \sinh x - 2 c_2 \sinh x
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

---

Solving the equation using Fourier transform, just like you I get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\hat{y}_1 \\ \hat{y}_2\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{-1}{1+\xi^2} \begin{pmatrix}i\xi+2 & -1 \\ 3 & i\xi-2\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}
$$
but then you make some mistakes. First you make a sign error. I get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\hat{y}_1 \\ \hat{y}_2\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{2}{1+\xi^2} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2-i\xi\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The right hand side is the Fourier transform of the convolution
$$
e^{-|x|} * \begin{pmatrix}\delta \\ 2\delta-\delta' \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}e^{-|x|} * \delta \\ e^{-|x|}*(2\delta-\delta') \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}e^{-|x|} \\ 2 e^{-|x|} - (e^{-|x|})' \end{pmatrix} \\
= \begin{pmatrix}e^{-|x|} \\ 2 e^{-|x|} + \operatorname{sign}(x) e^{-|x|} \end{pmatrix} 
= e^{-|x|} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 + \operatorname{sign}(x) \end{pmatrix}.
$$

Thus,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}{y}_1 \\ {y}_2\end{pmatrix}
= e^{-|x|} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 + \operatorname{sign}(x) \end{pmatrix}
+ \text{solutions to the homogeneous equation}.
$$

I should add something about the solutions to the homogeneous equation and also show that the two solutions are equal.

Comment: Seems totally different than my work

Comment: Yes, I didn't use the Fourier transform. But that should also work.

Comment: @md2prepe : Thanks a lot

Comment: @md2prep : But, 2cosh(x) - 2sinh(x) = 0, is it ok ?Would you please solve the problem using Fourier Transformation?

Comment: What makes you think that $2 \cosh x - 2 \sinh x = 0$?

Comment: If $coshx = \frac{e^x + e^ {-x} }{2}$ and $sinhx = \frac{e^x - e^ {-x}}{2}$ then $2coshx - 2sinhx = 2 e^{-x}$

Comment: Oh , I am sorry, OMG, I became mad :(

Comment: @TazimTaz. I've now added a solution using the Fourier transform. I should add some more into it, though.